# Does filestream.length represent the file size or where I actually stopped writing?

Tags: vb.net

If I were to build a filestream, I'd allocate hdd space in chunks. That got me wondering though, if I set the stream position to the stream length, will I start writing right where I left off the last time or will there be a gap which size depends on where the chunk left off?

Comment: This won't work correctly.  Allocating "chunks" is the job of the operating system's file system driver.  The proper name is "cluster".  Just stop helping and you won't have this problem.

Comment: 2 Questions.  1.  What is the purpose of this file that you are writing to.  2.  Are you reopening the file then writing to it. because if you are in the same write session you shouldnt have to do anything to continue writing where you left off.   But yes length represents the total length of the filestream so if you were to set the write point to the length you would be writing at the end of the file.